# Given a list of Tuples, return a new list of the first values of the tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and I want a new list consisting of the first values of the tuples.

I.e. if the list is:

[(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]

I want to create the following list:

[1,4,100,4]

The following code works:

```
a = [(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]
l = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    l.append(a[i][0])
```

But it seems there should be a better way, for example:

```
l = itertools.chain(for i in range(len(a)) a[i][0]) #This won't work
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a list comprehension:

```
l=[(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]
print [x[0] for x in l]
```

This will give you

```
[1, 4, 100, 4]
```

as requested :)

Answer (score 8):

I'd usually use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]
>>> [x for x, y in a]
[1, 4, 100, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do list comprehension, you could try this:

```
x = [(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]

first_vals = list(zip(*x)[0])
```

Result:

```
>>> first_vals
[1, 4, 100, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> a = [(1,5),(4,10),(100,3),(4,8)]
>>> [b[0] for b in a]
[1, 4, 100, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> map(lambda e: e[0], (e for e in a))
[1, 4, 100, 4]
```

Comment: `(e for e in a)` can be simplified to `a`.

Comment: Also you should use `operator.itemgetter(0)`. No need to use a user-defined function when there is a built-in one that does the same thing.